# Why no need app_context when use flask-script interact with models?

Tags: python, flask

My flask-script code is below, I read the document [appcontext](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/appcontext/):

```
from flask_script import Manager
from app import app
from models import User
from ext import db

manager = Manager(app)
db.init_app(app)

@manager.option('-u','--username',dest='username')
@manager.option('-p','--password',dest='password')
def add_user(username,password):
    user = User(username=username, password=password)
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
    print 'success'
```

why it success without a app_context.for example:

```
@manager.option('-u','--username',dest='username')
@manager.option('-p','--password',dest='password')
def add_user(username,password):
    with app.app_context():
        user = User(username=username, password=password)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        print 'success'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the flask-script declared in the app, to maintain the app context

Comment: thanks for you. i have read the source code of flask-script. and i found `Comment.__call__` method has a line `with app.test_request_context()`. so you are right,`test_request_context` will push a app context. thanks again~~~